# How can I create a user that is not allowed to change its own password on mediawiki?

Tags: mediawiki

I am currently creating a mediawiki where there are administrators and writers, and everyone else in the project only needs read access. Our current approach is having all the read-only users share a same login for accessibility. How can I ensure that this user is not able to change its own password?

Comment: You might do better to ask in a MediaWiki forum.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are better served by a HTTP password. That said, you can take away their `editmyprivateinfo` right to prevent changing passwords (and user preferences in general).

Comment: I can vouch for this approach. I had good luck using [Extension:Auth_remoteuser](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Auth_remoteuser) for this. The authentication/authorization was handled by the Apache web server, using `AuthType Basic` directives, and Extension:Auth_remote user just looks for the `REMOTE_USER` environment variable set by Apache.